# Website to practise OOP design skills

Tags: oop

Is there a website/list of problems which can be used to practice OOP design skills? Let's say if I am a colleague graduate familiar with object-oriented-design theory, these problems should give me a chance to exercise the theory and improve my software design skills.

Comment: I think it's just suppose to be "OOP". Rollback my edit if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 8):

If you're wanting to try out a new methodology or something, try making a small application just for you, or perhaps for internal use only. eg: A timesheet application, a task manager, a grocery list organiser, etc. Make sure it's a *real* problem, so you're forced to deal with *real* requirements. I've found that if you just play around and try things out, you tend to just ignore certain parts when they don't work immediately.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeKata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/) is a place to start.

It's not a web site, but Head First Design Patterns has a multitude of problems to solve.